# pgfplots memory overload

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to plot 5x9000+ data points. I am already using:

```
\usepgfplotslibrary{external} 
\tikzexternalize
```

and

```
-shell-escape -enable-write18
```

in PDFLatex. However, I still get the memory error. I am reading the data from a file like this:

```
\pgfplotstableread{C:\\data_1373554136.txt}
\datatable
%\addplot table[x = 0] from \datatable ;
\addplot table[y = 1] from \datatable ;
\addplot table[y = 2] from \datatable ;
\addplot table[y = 3] from \datatable ;
\addplot table[y = 4] from \datatable ;
\addplot table[y = 5] from \datatable ;
```

My data in the file looks like this:

```
Time    0   1   2   3   4   5
0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   1   7   19  1   115
```

I am running on Windows 7 using Miktex.

Any suggestions there?

Comment: The `external` library only helps with memory problems if the individual `tikzpicture` environments are small enough to compile correctly. In your case, try compiling the document with `lualatex` instead of `pdflatex`.

Comment: @Jake Probably that's the closest we can get to an answer: could you make it one?

Comment: @Jake See Joseph's comment.

Answer (score 6):

It might be late for an answer, but just for documentation.

In my case I found lualatex extremely slow.

Instead one could increase the memory manually for pgfplots externalization.
(numbers are chosen arbitrary to be large enough, you may want adjust them)

```
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz,shell escape=-enable-write18]

\tikzset{external/system call= {pdflatex -save-size=80000 
                           -pool-size=10000000 
                           -extra-mem-top=50000000 
                           -extra-mem-bot=10000000 
                           -main-memory=90000000 
                           \tikzexternalcheckshellescape 
                           -halt-on-error 
                           -interaction=batchmode
                           -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}
```

or you can use lualatex only for  externalization

```
\tikzset{external/system call= {lualatex
                           \tikzexternalcheckshellescape 
                           -halt-on-error 
                           -interaction=batchmode
                           -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}
```

Comment: What kind of `pdflatex` do you use? I'm on TeXLive2015 and `pdflatex` does not recognize those options for increasing memory.