# Memory overload due to pgfplots / tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tex-core, shell-escape, memory

first of all, I need to mention that there are 2 **related threads**, that I found usefull:
[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7953/how-to-expand-texs-main-memory-size-pgfplots-memory-overload), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123616/pgfplots-memory-overload).

I am working with `TeXstudio 2.8.8` on Win 7 64bit (i5 @3.3GHz, 8GB RAM - if this matters). My goal is to load multiple .tex files into my pdfLaTeX-document which have been created by `matlab2tikz`. It used to work fine, but since the datapoints have increased I and ran into the same problem as @user1996 in Link no. 1.
It still says: `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000].`

At the moment there are 2 documents: the fist hast 40000 lines of autogereated code and the second one 10000. (In an `\tikzpicture`-environment)

I tried the solution suggested by @Joseph Wright in [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7953/how-to-expand-texs-main-memory-size-pgfplots-memory-overload) but encountered the same problem as @Alexandre Willame described in his comment. I also tried the `enable-write18 -extra-mem-bot=10000000` (and higher numbers) option, suggested by @Thomas F. Sturm in [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7953/how-to-expand-texs-main-memory-size-pgfplots-memory-overload), but without success. The message is:`TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=13000000].` At a certian point I can't allocate more memory (`Virtual memory exhausted`), but it still gives me this message.

Finally I tried the way @A.GH suggested in [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123616/pgfplots-memory-overload). But this jeust resulted in an other (different) error message

I am really hoping for an answer / a way to implement the mentioned answers. **The most wanted solution is the one from @Joseph Wright.** But I don't know what's missing/wrong.

*Additional Info:*
[image: My TeXstudio Options]
(I am using pdfLaTeX)

In my preamble I wrote:

```
% TikZ
\usepackage{pgfplots}
% and optionally (as of Pgfplots 1.3):
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
\newlength\figureheight
\newlength\figurewidth
% "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000]."
\usepgfplotslibrary{external} 
\tikzexternalize
```

Comment: I think the simplest solution is to compile either the whole document using LuaLaTeX or at least put the plots responsible for the error message to a dummy file using the same/almost the same preamble and "externalize" them. Then this externalized files can be incorporated easily in your main document. The "externalization" can be done using either the `external` library of PGFPlots or using the `standalone` documentclass. (Searching here for examples will give you plenty of results, if you don't know what I am talking about.)